# Error getting HTTP response

Tags: java, oauth, gdata

I am trying to generate Request Token using following code :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, Base64DecoderException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, OAuthException {
//        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


        try {
            String CONSUMER_KEY = "www.google.com";

            GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
            oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
            oauthParameters.setScope("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
            oauthParameters.setOAuthCallback("callbackUrl.jsp");

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            keyGen.initialize(1024, random);

            KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey priv = (RSAPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();
            //PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();

            GoogleOAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(new OAuthRsaSha1Signer(priv));
            oauthHelper.getUnauthorizedRequestToken(oauthParameters);

            String approvalPageUrl = oauthHelper.createUserAuthorizationUrl(oauthParameters);
            System.out.println("Callback URL : " + approvalPageUrl);
            /* TODO output your page here
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet requestServlet</title>");  
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet requestServlet at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
             */
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

For sure, there is no compile time error here. But, getting runtime error i.e. :

```
   com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthException: Error getting HTTP response
            at com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthHttpClient.getResponse(OAuthHttpClient.java:76)
            at com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthHttpClient.getResponse(OAuthHttpClient.java:44)
            at com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthHelper.getUnauthorizedRequestToken(OAuthHelper.java:335)
            at Oauth.requestServlet.processRequest(requestServlet.java:56)
            at Oauth.requestServlet.doGet(requestServlet.java:88)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?oauth_callback=callbackUrl.jsp&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Ffeeds%2F&oauth_nonce=6077341098309&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=www.google.com&oauth_timestamp=1296198416&oauth_signature=h%2F0IlDlsMYy2HqXv%2FksrOX3XCm51IwwpoRMjgLwGOJXTwSbZkTP%2FguIH7ZRXfL16DtHAlULhyyvqapCR3pSA%2BKqZdcr5kdHMHWlnRGglHQb54X%2BT8EOWPr9xTQOd0DDbQrLvau6RJhhSFxov95mU2UDQa2vI%2FRoyVMpAGqNUi4c%3D
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
            at com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthHttpClient.getResponse(OAuthHttpClient.java:66)
            ... 30 more
```

What is my error here ? Here, the scope url is correct for sure. You can try it for your google Url as well. If still the error has been with the requestUrl itself, please help what it can be ?

Also, when I throw the request to request Url that is `"https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?oauth_callback=callbackUrl.jsp&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Ffeeds%2Fspreadsheets%2Fprivate%2Ffull&oauth_nonce=7977789106925&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=www.google.com&oauth_timestamp=1296200317&oauth_signature=FFNlR4vB%2FOAs3006VGG4wKQkB3TbGDmyg4KN04YvicZfQ6Y9%2FHp5ZVinyhTI5YB%2BQmxFu%2BPXGL3iQcVCr2Ap2Y4abwMnX%2Bi4q3%2FvNMr8g1IGJvJJ%2FPu9x5rIQHiJPNLmCdGCjlXOZLIM5%2BuLv0zDWc%2B6cDFCess0Iuzhh%2BdqP6I%3D",` it gives me error of Wrong Signature !!! :(

Comment: For reference : http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html#keytool

Comment: I'd probably recommend using the HMAC-SHA1 signature method in this case.  Much easier to debug.  Also your callback URI **must** be absolute.  You may also find the OAuth Playground helpful: http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the URL which is causing an HTTP 400 error. See:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?oauth_callback=callbackUrl.jsp&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Ffeeds%2F&oauth_nonce=6077341098309&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=www.google.com&oauth_timestamp=1296198416&oauth_signature=h%2F0IlDlsMYy2HqXv%2FksrOX3XCm51IwwpoRMjgLwGOJXTwSbZkTP%2FguIH7ZRXfL16DtHAlULhyyvqapCR3pSA%2BKqZdcr5kdHMHWlnRGglHQb54X%2BT8EOWPr9xTQOd0DDbQrLvau6RJhhSFxov95mU2UDQa2vI%2FRoyVMpAGqNUi4c%3D         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)         at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)         at com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthHttpClient.getResponse(OAuthHttpClient.java:66)         ... 30 more
```

Verify your URL is correct. More info about HTTP 400 Error, click [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html).

Comment: Ok ! It may be the error of timeStamp. Do you know how to modify this time stamp ? "oauth_timestamp=1296198416"

Comment: I think you want to have the `oauth_callback` parameter be an absolute URL, like http://www.yoursite.com/callbackUrl.jsp

Comment: @user284291: How about sharing your solution. Thanks.